# Testing if dynamic method call was received using RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to test if a dynamic method call was performed using RSpec. Having a bit of trouble.

I have code that looks like :

```
def self.parse_file
  method_name = "parse_#{get_file_type}"
  send method_name
end

def self.parse_gz
  ....
end
```

Assuming that get_file_type returns "gz", I want to test that parse_gz is called from the parse_file instance method.

Initially, I was thinking something like below, but I think I'm going about it wrong...

```
Class.should_receive(:parse_gz).with(Class.parse_file)
```

...that doesn't work

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Does just `Class.should_receive(:parse_gz)` work?

Answer (score 0):

Your version does not work, because you never call `parse_gz`with an argument.Try this:

```
Class.should_receive(:parse_file)
```

or

```
Class.should_receive(:send).with('parse_gz')
```

Furthermore I would suggest to use the new `allow(thing).to receive(method)` syntax instead of the old `thing.should_receive(method)` syntax.